# iOS: how to populate button image from passed image string

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently I have a `RootViewController` and a `PopViewController` (popover segue).

In `RootViewController` I have a `imageView` (*card) which DOES populate with the image file from  `NSString *value` passed from `PopViewController`.

I also have a `Button` (*cardButton) where I would really like this string generated image file to be populated.

RootViewController.m

```
- (void)dismissPop:(NSString *)value {
NSString *imagefile;
imagefile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",value];
//card.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagefile];
cardButton.currentBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imagefile];

[[currentPopoverSegue popoverController] dismissPopoverAnimated: YES]; // dismiss the popover
}

@end
```

I have zero prior programming education and have solely gotten this far interpreting similar code. I've played around with the syntax of `UIButton`-line

```
cardButton.currentBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imagefile];
```

trying to make a `UIButton` equivalent of the `UIImageView`-line

```
card.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagefile];
```

which works.

With current code I get !Assignment to readonly property (ERROR).
please help

Comment: I'm new to this forum, just curious why i shouldn't tag this as Xcode since I'm working on the project through Xcode?

Comment: Perfect question. The thing is that it doesn't matter using which IDE you are developing the project. The essential is that its target is iOS and you're using the Cocoa Touch APIs with the Objective-C language. See, I've been developing apps since more than two years, and I've barely used Xcode :) Make and clang does the job pretty well.

Comment: `Xcode` tag is for problems which are related to `Xcode` software. And I think your `Xcode` is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the image use this code

```
[cardButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagefile] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And if you really want to change background image then use this

```
[cardButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagefile] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```